# Unable to capture WooCommerce REST API request which is causing PHP error

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a third party application which inserts product data to WooCommerce via the REST API. The third party application does not log outbound API requests.

The third party application is making a request to WooCommerce which is causing a PHP error.

```
[16-Jan-2023 14:52:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: preg_match(): Argument #2 ($subject) must be of type string, WP_REST_Request given in /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:1596
Stack trace:
#0 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(1596): preg_match('/[\\x80-\\xff]/', Object(WP_REST_Request))
#1 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(2207): remove_accents(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#2 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): sanitize_title(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#3 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Object(WP_REST_Request), Array)
#4 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php(1751): apply_filters('pre_term_slug', Object(WP_REST_Request), 'pa_colour')
#5 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php(1653): sanitize_term_field('slug', Object(WP_REST_Request), 0, 'pa_colour', 'db')
#6 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php(2385): sanitize_term(Array, 'pa_colour', 'db')
#7 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version3/class-wc-rest-terms-controller.php(407): wp_insert_term('DENIM BLUE', 'pa_colour', Array)
#8 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1171): WC_REST_Terms_Controller->create_item(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#9 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1018): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request(Object(WP_REST_Request), '/wc/v2/products...', Array, NULL)
#10 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(442): WP_REST_Server->dispatch(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#11 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api.php(410): WP_REST_Server->serve_request('/wc/v2/products...')
#12 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): rest_api_loaded(Object(WP))
#13 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#14 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#15 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(399): do_action_ref_array('parse_request', Array)
#16 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(780): WP->parse_request('')
#17 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1332): WP->main('')
#18 /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#19 /home/CENSORED/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/CENSORED...')
#20 {main}
thrown in /home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1596
```

I believe the PHP error is a bug that needs to be reported to WooCommerce and/or WordPress. I am unable to capture the contents of the request so that I can provide steps to reproduce for the bug report.

I am testing on a completely blank and up-to-date installation of WordPress and WooCommerce with no other plugins (except those mentioned below).

I have tried:

- Looking in the Apache access log, the request body is not included
- Using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-log/ but it does not capture the request. It captures valid requests, but not the request that causes the error
- Using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/log-http-requests/ it does not appear to capture REST API requests
- Using this code https://iandunn.name/2016/02/05/logging-wordpress-rest-api-errors/ it does not add any content to the error_log when the error occurs. I fired other invalid requests to the REST API and it did work, so I can only assume that the request is a valid REST API request syntactically and the resulting error is an internal PHP bug.

How can I capture the full request so that I can confirm this is a WooCommerce or WordPress bug and report to the appropriate github?

Comment: Is your third party application a web app?

Comment: @Olivier afraid not, it’s a desktop app. I considered a packet sniffer but seems overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest: "debugging by printf" or "debugging by `print_r`" in this special case.

Edit `/home/CENSORED/public_html/index.php` and insert just before line 17:

```php
syslog(LOG_ERROR, print_r($_GET, TRUE));
syslog(LOG_ERROR, print_r($_POST, TRUE));
```

depending on the request type your plugin fires, the content should appear in one of these log outputs.

You could also go to `/home/CENSORED/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php` and insert before line 1596:

```php
syslog(LOG_ERROR, print_r($text, TRUE));
```

to get the malformed string variable.

After doing so, you should be able to find the log lines in the server's syslog via:

```bash
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

If you unfortunately don't have access to the wp source code on the server machine, you should capture the request on the desktop machine which is running the plugin via [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCapturingSection.html) or [TShark](https://opensource.com/article/20/1/wireshark-linux-tshark). I wouldn't blame it overkill. By filtering the capture by server IP, protocol http and method (`http.request.method == GET` or `http.request.method == POST`) the heart of the matter should be revealed soon (Maybe you have to reset the request scheme from `https` to `http`).

Comment: @robbie-lewis Did you have any success with the "debugging"? Btw. you could just use the `$_REQUEST` super global to printout the whole info for every type of request.